# Defining constants in index file

Tags: php, scope, constants

my application routes every request through an index file. This file has

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/config/config.php"`.

This config file defines path constants so they can be used elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to work. For example in config.php I have

`define('MODELS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/models/");`.

In one of the model files I am trying to include another class such as

`require_once MODELS . "classA.php"`

`class classB {.....}`

I get an error for undefined constant MODELS. Any ideas how to fix this? I would ideally like for these constants to be accessible from anywhere in my application.

config.php:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
define("APP",$root . "app/"); // app folder
define("CONFIG",$root . "app/config/"); // config folder
define("MODELS",$root . "app/models/"); // models folder
define("CONTROLLERS",$root . "app/controllers/"); // controllers folder
define("DB",$root . "app/db/"); // database connection folder
define("VIEWS",$root . "app/views/"); // views folder
define("FUNCTIONS",$root . "app/functions/"); // functions folder
define("LIBRARY",$root . "app/library/"); // library folder
define("PUBLIC",$root . "public/"); // public folder
```

index.php:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/db/dbconnect.php";
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/config/config.php";
require_once FUNCTIONS . "clean.php";
require_once MODELS . "core.php";
require_once MODELS . "user.php";
require_once MODELS . "browser.php";
require_once MODELS . "call.php";
require_once MODELS . "module.php";
```

error comes from some file:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Send")
{
require_once MODELS . "contact.php";
$contact = new contact();
}
```

Comment: `define('MODELS', $value)`

Comment: @u_mulder sorry, that was a typo, my actual code does include quotes

Comment: Either you name constants wrong or your config file not included.

Comment: @u_mulder, but I use the constants further down in my index file, and they work fine?

Comment: Are you sure that in `some file` there's an inclusion of `config.php`?

Comment: no there isn't. Seeing as the config file is included in the index file, and the page is loaded from the index file, wouldn't the constants from config be available to the page

Comment: Yes they will, but obvioulsy in your case `config.php` is not included. Check other constants values, make sure that `config.php` really included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick fix but bad idea:

Use your index.php file as global reference point together with the PHP magical constant `__DIR__`.

index.php

```
require_once __DIR__."/config.php"; // This loads your constants
```

config.php

```
define('PATH', __DIR__."/any_folder_you_want"); // Repeat this for your folders
```

## Doing it right:

Generally speaking, you don't want to organize your project that way since it might lead to major arquitectual problems in the future.

Solutions:

- learn how to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)
- implement a PSR-4 Autoloading strategy yourself. [Example here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/)